# Bootstrap over index?

Tags: php, frameworks

I am working on making a PHP Framework, mostly as a learning experience and to test my knowledge about what is 'smart' for a framework.

One thing I find puzzling is the bootstrap, I understand it's a great place to start sessions, set up a registry and have other things to start up your application.

However, what I don't understand is... why not put that in the index.php?

In my experience, both the bootstrap and the index.php are small files. Sometimes the bootstrap is quite large but the index never is.

So why would I bother with a separate bootstrap file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anything your code, you can put it into as many files as you like. If you dislike separating code into files because of their meaning ([modularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularity)), then just mesh everything into one file.

Clever persons however separate stuff (modularity). If modular becomes a hindrance, they just use automation (see [build automation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation)) to just build one file out of multiple.

> So why would I bother with a separate bootstrap file?

So the only one who can answer your question is you. Therefore please decide on your own:

```
  [ ] I have a reason to separate
  [ ] I have no reason to separate
```

The important part is that you think about it. Try to find arguments for and against, list them next to each other. Decide.

Comment: "Try to find arguments for and against" is basicly why I'm asking this question here, thanks for your input :)

Comment: @John: In my opinion it's a design-decision anyway and nothing where you could say, that one of the two decisions is the way to go ... You really have to ask yourself, if your framework requires this separation, find pro/cons yourself. I think nobody will be able to give you the final answer on this. I -- for example -- prefer to put this stuff into index.php, because i see no need in putting it elsewhere ...

Comment: :) - But that's the point. I *suggest* you to look into build automation. Unless you don't want to, separate code by concerns. That helps you to keep design decisions specific, which is helpful if you want to learn. But that's my opinion, for your framework this *could* be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It will be easier to use different bootstrap files for different application environments, for example a testing, development, staging or production environment. You can decide for yourself if you need this flexibility.

Comment: I'm using different methods of making that distinction, (enviroment_env for example) still, you raise a good point...

Comment: A nice solution would be for you to have all your environment specific code in the bootstrap file, and that you decide which bootstrap file to load based on the value of the ENVIRONMENT_ENV constant.

Comment: I use different config-files for this, which get automatically included by a the value of an environment variable. Testing and production should not be too different from each other, because what's the purpose of testing than anyway, and therefore i would not need any different PHP code for testing and therefore i would not need differen bootstrap scripts -- but only different configuration files (eg. database configuration, caching, etc.)

Comment: Yeah, in that case you can create a single bootstrap file and include the right configuration script. But my answer to his question only was to point out a possible reason for creating a bootstrap file. If he actually needs one is up to him to decide.

Answer (score 1):

Another point to consider is, how paranoid you want to be about the files that sit in your public folder(s)